# Can't add windows to markers in Angular Google Map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I'm trying to add windows (info bubbles) to markers in an Angular Google Map. I'm using the Ionic Framework.

Markup:

```
<google-map
    center="map.center"
    zoom="map.zoom"
  <marker
    ng-repeat="marker in markers"
    coords="marker"
    <window
      show="true"
      templateUrl="templates/map-info-window.html">
    </window>
  </marker>
</google-map>
```

JS:

```
  $scope.markers = [];

  $scope.populateMarkers = function(locations) {
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      $scope.addMarker(locations[i].Latitude, locations[i].Longitude);
    }
  }

  $scope.addMarker = function (lat, lng) {

    $scope.markers.push({
        latitude: parseFloat(lat),
        longitude: parseFloat(lng)
    });
  }
```

I want to add a `window` for each `marker`. The [Angular GoogleMaps documentation](http://angular-google-maps.org/api#marker) says you can include `window` within a `marker`  to use its coordinates.

But the code above does not work. For each `window` I try to add I get this error:

```
Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.12/jqLite/nosel
    at http://localhost:8888/anggmaps/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9007:12
    at JQLite (http://localhost:8888/anggmaps/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11072:13)
    at compile (http://localhost:8888/anggmaps/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14439:25)
    at WindowChildModel.buildContent (http://localhost:8888/anggmaps/www/lib/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js:491:24)
    at WindowChildModel.createWindowOptions (http://localhost:8888/anggmaps/www/lib/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js:471:29)
    at WindowChildModel.createGWin (http://localhost:8888/anggmaps/www/lib/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js:1901:30)
    at WindowChildModel.createGWin (http://localhost:8888/anggmaps/www/lib/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js:1822:63)
    at new WindowChildModel (http://localhost:8888/anggmaps/www/lib/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js:1856:16)
    at http://localhost:8888/anggmaps/www/lib/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js:3898:24
    at http://localhost:8888/anggmaps/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22538:28 ionic.bundle.js:18364
(anonymous function) ionic.bundle.js:18364
(anonymous function) ionic.bundle.js:15775
(anonymous function) ionic.bundle.js:22541
completeOutstandingRequest ionic.bundle.js:13040
(anonymous function)
```

It happens as I push the windows into the $scope.windows array, but it only throws that error after all windows are pushed into the array, I don't know which moment precisely.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

I updated the above code, now it seems to be right, because (please correct me if I'm wrong):

I don't need to have a $scope.windows array. Each `marker` directive has a `window` directive inside of it, so It's already there - it's not like `markers in marker`, where I should populate the markers array, for the ng-repeat directive to iterate through them.

Now, I still get the error. What's wrong?

ps:

I loaded jQuery to see if that was the problem, but then it gave me a different, probably unrelated error:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ionTabs', required by directive 'ngClass', can't be found!
```

Comment: `$scope.windows.push();` - what are you trying to push into the windows array?

Comment: oops, it should be an empty object (for the example). I unintentionally removed the brackets when simplifying the code

Comment: @Zok, indeed the way to go is to add jQuery to your application. JQLite which comes with angular is not enough. Try fixing the $compile error and see where you are.

Comment: thanks @victor- yes, I got it to work with jQuery 1.x (only 2.x throwed that error. i posted about that somewhere but I can't find it now). anyway, right now I'm working on my own google maps directive for angular. and sorry, but what do you mean with "fixing the $compile error"? thank you